# How do I load ManyToOne Entities with YML

Tags: hibernate, playframework, yaml

I have the following yml and entities.
Every time I load the yml via Fixtures.loadModels(), every entity get persisted but the vsCat_id foreign key on VSCode is always null and the relationship is not persisted.

What i'm I missing here?

```
yml: 

VSCode(VS960):
   vsCode: VS960
   description: blabla

VSCategory(dvs1):
   name: Category 1
   vsCodes:
      - VSA960
      - VSA961


public class VSCode extends GenericModel {
    @Id
    public String            vsCode;
    public String            description;

    @ManyToOne
    public VSCategory vsCat;

    public VSCode(String code, String description) {
        this.vsCode = code;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

@Entity
public class VSCategory extends Model {

    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="vsCat")
    public Set<VSCode> vsCodes;

    public VSCategory(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.vsCodes = new HashSet();
    }
}
```